How to configure Azure API Management to deny all requests by default but allow specific APIs?
I need to configure an API in Azure API Management to deny all incoming requests by default, regardless of their content or authentication. My goal is to ensure that the base policy denies all requests. However, there are some specific APIs that should work correctly and allow valid requests.
Here's the policy configuration I think might work:
                <claim name="roles" separator=" ">
                    <value>deny_all</value>
                </claim>

I have set the validate-jwt policy to check for a specific claim (roles) with a value that is never valid (deny_all). This is intended to deny all requests by default.
Could someone provide guidance or a better approach to achieve this?
Additionally, I want to ensure that specific APIs with correct key and value in the JWT should be allowed to function normally, while the base policy remains restrictive.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe configure set-status in the global scope to return status code 401?

Hi Rui, could you provide a quick guide on how to configure set-status in the global scope? I'm new to Azure APIM and have only set up JWT policies so far. Thank @RuiJarimba

I don't have much experience myself configuring policies for APIM. Global scope policies can be configured in the "All APIs" section.


My goal is to ensure that the base policy denies all requests. However, there are some specific APIs that should work correctly and allow valid requests.

You need to add validate-jwt policy in All APIs scope as shown below-

This will allow some specific APIs to function normally with valid values and will restrict others. You don't need to set the status for 401 because if the JWT token is not correct then eventually you will get 401 unauthorized error message.
Another way is to use the Products. Add the policy in a Product and then add set of APIs to that Product.
You can add the APIs by clicking on Add API in the Overview blade.

In Policies blade, add the policies you need to configure for the APIs present in that Product.


thank you very much I will try to test and study further.
